# Why MongoDB is Consistent not available and Cassandra is Available not consistent?

Tags: mongodb, cassandra

**Mongo**

From this [resource](https://scalegrid.io/blog/cassandra-vs-mongodb/) I understand why mongo is not `A(Highly Available)` based on below statement

> MongoDB supports a “single master” model. This means you have a master
>   node and a number of slave nodes. In case the master goes down, one of
>   the slaves is elected as master. This process happens automatically
>   but it takes time, usually 10-40 seconds. During this time of new
>   leader election, your replica set is down and cannot take writes

Is it for the same reason Mongo is said to be `Consistent`(as write did not happen so returning the latest data in system ) but not `Available`(not available for writes) ?

Till re-election happens and write operation is in pending, can slave return perform the read operation ? Also does user re-initiate the write operation again once master is selected ?

**But i do not understand from another angle** why Mongo is `highly consistent`
As said on [Where does mongodb stand in the CAP theorem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292215/where-does-mongodb-stand-in-the-cap-theorem),

> Mongo is `consistent` when all reads go to the primary by default.

But that is not true. If under Master/slave model , all reads will go to primary what is the use of slaves then ? It further says  `If you optionally enable reading from the secondaries then MongoDB becomes eventually consistent where it's possible to read out-of-date results.` It means mongo may not be be 
consistent with master/slaves(provided i do not configure write to all nodes before return).  It does not makes sense to me to say mongo is consistent if all
read and writes go to primary. In that case every other DB also(like cassandra) will be consistent . Is n't it ?

**Cassandra**
From this [resource](https://scalegrid.io/blog/cassandra-vs-mongodb/)  I understand why Cassandra is `A(Highly Available )` based on below statement

> Cassandra supports a “multiple master” model. The loss of a single
>   node does not affect the ability of the cluster to take writes – so
>   you can achieve 100% uptime for writes

**But I do not understand** why cassandra is not `Consistent` ?  Is  it because node not available for write(as coordinated node is not able to connect) is available for read which can return stale data ?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 19):

Go through: [MongoDB, Cassandra, and RDBMS in CAP](https://medium.com/@bikas.katwal10/mongodb-vs-cassandra-vs-rdbms-where-do-they-stand-in-the-cap-theorem-1bae779a7a15), for better understanding of the topic.

A brief definition of `Consistency` and `availability`.

**Consistency** simply means, when you write a piece of data in a system/distributed system, the same data you should get when you read it from any node of the system.

**Availability** means, the system should always be available for read/write operation.

**Note: Most systems are not, only available or only consistent, they always offer a bit of both**

With the above definition let's see where MongoDB and Cassandra fall in CAP.

**MongoDB**

As you said MongoDB is `highly consistent` when reads and write go to the same node(the default case). Further, you can choose in MongoDB to read from other secondary nodes instead of reading from only leader/primary.

Now, when you try to read data from secondary, your consistency will completely depend on, how you want to read data:

- You could ask data which is up to maximum, say 5 seconds stale or,
- You could just say, return data from `majority` of nodes for your `select` statement.

Same way when you write from your client into Mongo leader, you can say, a write is successful if the data is replicated to or stored on `majority` of servers.

Clearly, from above, we can say MongoDb can be highly consistent or eventually consistent based on how you read/write your data.

Now, what about availability? MongoDB is mostly always available, but, the only time when the leader is down, MongoDB can't accept writes, until it figures out the new leader.  Hence, not `highly available`

So, MongoDB is categorized under CP.

**What about Cassandra?**

In Cassandra, there is no leader and any nodes can accept write, so the Cassandra cluster is always available for writes and reads even if some nodes go down.

**What about consistency in Cassandra?**
Same as MongoDB Cassandra can be eventually consistent or highly consistent based on how you read/write data.

You can give consistency levels in your read/write operations, For example:

- read/write data from one node
- read/write data from majority/quorum of nodes and more

Let's say you give a consistency level of one in your read/write operation. So, your write is successful as soon as data is written to one replica. Now, if your read request happens to go to the other replica where the data is not updated yet(could be due to high network latency or any other reason), you will end up reading the old data.

So, Cassandra is highly available but has configurable consistency levels and hence not always consistent.

In conclusion, in their default behavior, MongoDB falls under CP and Cassandra in AP.

Comment: Further, you can choose in MongoDB to read from other secondary nodes instead of reading from only leader/primary => Essentially in this read preference mode we can say Mongodb is "read available" but still not "write available" , as writes shall still be served by the leader node.

Answer (score 2):

Consistency in the CAP paradigm also includes "eventual consistency" which MongoDB supports. In a contrast to ACID systems, the read in CAP systems does *not* guarantee a safe return.

In simple words, this means that your Master could have an updated value, but if you do read from Slave, it does not necessarily return the updated value, and that it's okay to no have this updated value by design.

The concept of eventual consistency is explained in an excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078540/eventual-consistency-in-plain-english).

By architecture, Cassandra is supposed to be consistent; it offers a special implementation of eventual consistency called the 'tunable consistency' which would meant that the client application may choose the method of handling this- it even offers multi data centre consistency support at low levels! 
Most issues from row wise inconsistency in Cassandra comes from the fact that  Cassandra uses client timestamps to determine which value is the most recent, and not the server side ones, which may be  tad bit confusing to understand at first.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I am not able to understand why mongo is said to be CP but cassandra is AP ?  Ragarding mongo db support for "eventual consistency", I believe this is true for cassandra also but a node can give stale data but eventually it will be consistent . Is n't it ?

Comment: Can you please explain any scenario where cassandra may not be eventually consistent ? Consider we have three nodes C1,C2 and C3 . Client writes(W1) to C1  but it gets down before writing to replication node(C2).  Now read/write request will be served by C2(which was earlier served by C1). Now when C1 gets back after sometime , Data W1 will be written to Node C2 also which makes Cassandra also eventual consistent. Then why cassandra is said to be not consitent(or eventual consistent) ?

Answer (score 0):

You have only to understand the "point-in-time": As you only write to mongodb master, even if slave is not updated, it is consistent, as it has all the data generated util the sync moment.

That is not true for cassandra. As cassandra uses a master-less model, there's no garantee that other nodes has all the data. At a certain time, a node can have certain recent data, and not having older data from nodes not yet synced. Cassandra will only be consistent if you stop write to all nodes and put them online. As soon the sync finished you have a consistent data.